# Customising and invoking methods on child component when repeating component in parent

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am literally 2 weeks into Angular so please bear with me.

**Context**

I have a parent component which gets a sentence from a service. The parent component will iterate through this sentence (list of words) passing each word in to a child word component for rendering.

**The goal**

I have a word component which contains a button element. The idea was that this component would be able to have functionality which would allow a parent component to customise the word component passing in css styles and to also invoke methods like Disable/Enable/Show/Hide.

**The problem**

As a newbie I'm kind of stuck between 2 types of communication model with the child component. @Input/@Output to customise the child component but needing @ViewChildren to invoke methods on that child component. As a result I'm kind of getting confused with how to invoke actions on a specific instance of a child word component. I can use the keyword "this" when an event occurs on the child component and so any functionality captured in my onClick() method will target the correct component. However my HideButton() and ShowButton() are not associated with an event and this will not have the correct context. If I expand the HideButton/ShowButton methods to take an id and then search the DOM it just seems a bad approach to have this mixture of the component referring to it's instance in events with this and then capturing general component behaviour search the DOM for an element based on it's id. Based on the goal can someone point me in the right direction to achieve what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you for your time.

**word.component.html**

```html
<button type="button" class="{{buttonClass}}" id="{{word.id}}" [disabled]="disabled">{{word.value}}</button>
```

**word.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Word} from '../word';

@Component({
  selector: 'word',
  templateUrl: './word.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./word.component.css'],
  host: { '(click)': 'onClick($event)'}
})
export class WordComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() word: Word;
  @Input() visibleCSSClass: string;
  @Input() invisibleCSSClass: string;

  @Output() selectedWord = new EventEmitter<Word>();

  disabled: boolean;
  buttonClass : string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonClass = this.visibleCSSClass;
    this.disabled = false;
  }

  public onClick(event: Event) 
  {    
    if(this.ButtonIsVisible())
    {
      this.HideButton();
      this.selectedWord.emit(this.word);
    }
  }

  private ButtonIsVisible()
  {
     return this.buttonClass === this.visibleCSSClass;
  }

  public HideButton()
  {
    this.buttonClass = this.invisibleCSSClass;
  }

  public ShowButton()
  {
    this.buttonClass = this.visibleCSSClass;
  }

  public EnableButton()
  {
    this.disabled = false;
  }

  public DisableButton()
  {
    this.disabled = true;
  }
```

**(Parent Component) parent.component.html**

```html
...

<ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let word of sentence | shuffle; last as isLast">
        <word [word]="word" [invisibleCSSClass]="'invisibleCSSClass'" [visibleCSSClass]="'visibleCSSClass'" (selectedWord)="wordSelected(word)" id="{{word.id}}"></word>
        <span *ngIf="!isLast">&nbsp;</span>
      </ng-container><br/><br/> 
      <button (click)="onSubmitClick()">Submit</button><br/><p></p>
    </ng-container>
    
...
```

**UPDATE**
I needed to add an id attribute to the word component and also give it a #identifier. Then I could use @ViewChildren to access the correct component and call methods on it where the **this** keyword had the context.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is really unclear. Could you please provide a [mcve] of your issue on https://stackblitz.com, so that we can see your code in action, and the issue that comes with it ?

Comment: you shouldnt "search the dom". Also, you cannot invoke methods on a child component without a reference to those components. Maybe you could trigger events in the container that the child are listening for